# UPDATED: Magento add customer attribute filter to order grid

Tags: mysql, custom-attributes, magento, mysql-error-1052

I have extended the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` class with a custom module to add several customer attributes (Magento EE 1.10) to the grid.

Two of the attributes I added are text fields (i.e. they live in the `customer_entity_varchar` table, and I was able to add them to the collection and display them in the grid.  So far so good.

A third attribute is a select, so the values live in the `customer_entity_int`, the `eav_attribute_option` and the `eav_attribute_option_value` tables.  I added the necessary values to the collection (using `$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(.....)`.  Again, so far so good.

My problem is being able to display **and** filter the attribute at the same time.

Inside the `_prepareColumns()` function in my `MyCompany_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid` class, if I add a column like this, - as expected - I can display the values of the attribute on each row, but I don't get a drop down filter in the header:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    ...
    $this->addColumn('bureau', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bureau'),
        'index'     => 'bureau',
        'type'      => 'text'
    ));
    ...
}
```

Following the example of `status`, and adding the column like this, gives me the drop down filter in the header, but it no longer displays the values for the attribute in each row:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    ...
    $this->addColumn('bureau', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bureau'),
        'index'     => 'bureau',
        'type'      => 'options',
        'options'   => $this->_getBureauOptions(),
        'filter_index' => 'value_option_table.option_id'
    ));
    ...
}   

protected function _getBureauOptions()
{
    $bureau = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
        ->setCodeFilter('bureau')
        ->getFirstItem();

    $bureauOptions = $bureau->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    $optionsArr = array();

    foreach ($bureauOptions as $option) {
        $optionsArr[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
    }

    return $optionsArr;
}
```

Any advice / explanation would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
It turns out that my code also causes a SQL error in a multi-website environment when an admin user only has permissions for some websites:
`"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'store_id' in where clause is ambiguous"`

Comment: When the column type is text are the displayed values integers as stored in the database or text as resolved from the options?

Comment: @clockworkgeek they are the text resolved from the attribute options - is that the problem? Should my join be pulling the integer values?

Comment: I suspect it should be retrieving integer values when using `options` type but wasn't sure. If you know how to do that already then give it a try!

Comment: @clockworkgeek brilliant - that did the trick - so obvious in retrospect. Since you are on a roll, would you have any idea why `store_id` is ambiguous (in MySQL query) in a multi-website setup with for an admin user who does not have privileges for all websites?

Comment: My best guess would be something to do with how those extra tables are joined. I think if you were to give more details it would warrant it's own question, it's complicated enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@clockworkgeek had the answer to the first part of my question.

The problem was that my `joinLeft()` was retrieving text values from the attribute options, while I should have been retrieving integer values when using `'type => 'options'`.

Once I changed my `joinLeft()` to only retrieve integer values from `customer_entity_int` (actually a simpler join), the filtering and display worked flawlessly - thank you sir.

I will re-post my second issue (about SQL errors caused by permissions) as a separate question.